# Make Nginx follow symlinks

Tags: symlink, nginx

Nginx does not follow symbolic links. I get a 404 error. In my directory, I have this link:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    48 Sep 23 08:52 modules -> /path/to/dir/
```

but the files stored in `/path/to/dir` aren't found.

Comment: Have a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks

Comment: OK i resolved with `disable_symlinks off;`. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.Have a nice day!

Comment: Please either type your solution as an answer and accept it (it's fair behaviour here) or elsewhere delete your question.

Comment: Any other ideas? I'm having this problem, I tried putting disable_symlinks off; in my conf (even though that is actually the default anyways) and nothing is working.

Comment: @Jason make sure the path to the symlinked file is readable and executable, e.g. run chmod +rx on all the preceding folders, and the file itself.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I insert `disable_symlinks off;` in my nginx.conf and i resolved, works fine!

```
http {
    disable_symlinks off;
}
```

Comment: I got `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "disable_symlinks" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:22` after doing this. I was using `nginx/1.8.0` on Mac OS X.

Comment: @frozen-flame `disable_symlinks` was added in version 1.1.15 ([see docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks)), so it should have worked. Are you sure you were on 1.8.0, and that it was in the allowed context (http, server, or location)?

Comment: Context to use `disable_symlinks`: `http, server, location`

Answer (score 6):

Use 'bind' option by mounting folders =)

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Type:

```
/path/where/my/big/files_dir /var/www/myhost/media_dir bind defaults,bind 0 0
```

(no symlinks & don't forget restart vds/cpu)

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution on [this post](https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126).

More specifically, these lines:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
```